# Synaptic Package manager not showing installed package virtualenv

Tags: synaptic, virtualenv

This is sort of confusing. I have synaptic package manager version 0.84.3(latest). It is showing virtualenv as 'not installed' although it has been installed. When i do the following in CLI

```
virtualenv --version
```

It tells the version of `virtualenv` which is `16.4.0`

BUT

when i do

```
apt-cache policy virtualenv
```

It shows

```
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 15.1.0+ds-1.1
```

Any thoughts appreciated!

EDIT:

> ```
> $ which virtualenv
> /home/user/.local/bin/virtualenv
>
> $ dpkg -S $(which virtualenv)
> dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /home/user/.local/bin/virtualenv
> ```

Comment: To be completely sure about the method how it was installed - please add output of `which virtualenv` and `dpkg -S $(which virtualenv)` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert - Answered your question in the edit.

Comment: The `/home/user/.local/bin/virtualenv` is not maintained by APT in any way.

Answer (score 1):

If `virtualenv` was installed from source code, rather than a .deb or PPA, then Synaptics and APT will be unaware of the program installed.

As your version of `virtualenv` was only released 2/22/2019 and not available in Launchpad or the Ubuntu repositories, I assume that it was installed from source.

Comment: Would your answer change after my question edit?

Comment: @VishalMahajan No, but it does resolve a little bit about who installed the program!

Comment: Thanks for the info Charles. I now remember that i installed it(virtualenv) using pip3 command. I think that is why APT & Synaptics were unaware.

Comment: @VishalMahajan That's likely the case.  Because of *where* it is installed, it is only visible to your account.  I imagine that you have been writing some program to be run under another user?

Comment: I was just trying to get started with TensorFlow. So i was following an instructor without knowing what's going under the hood.